# Displaying error message on SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException Exception in Jsf

Tags: java, sql, jsf-2, error-handling

I want to notify the user on SQLException in my jsf page with `<h:messages/>`

I have the following function

```
 public String createAccount() throws RollbackFailureException,SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException,Exception{
    String status = "failure";
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Registering the user");
        utx.begin();
        em = getEntityManager();

        em.persist();
        status = "success";
        utx.commit();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception re) {
            throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
        }
        if (findDetails(details.getId()) != null) {

          throw new SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException("Your Account cannot be setup as the Login Id already exists.Kindly choose a different Login ID", ex);
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
```

How do I show the error message with jsf??

Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following in your backing bean to add a message:

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
...
FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, msg);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMsg);
```

The severity can alternatively be `SEVERITY_WARN` or `SEVERITY_INFO`. You can give a clientId as first paramter of `addMessage`. If it is `null`, the message is a global message and shown in `h:messages`.

Comment: Put it there where you handle your exception.